# How do I resolve an IP into host using c-ares?

Tags: c++, linux, dns, c-ares

This is what I've done so far. It compiles, but it segfaults when I try to run it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <ares.h>

void dns_callback (void* arg, int status, int timeouts, struct hostent* host)
  {
    std::cout << host->h_name << "\n";
  }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
    struct in_addr ip;
    char *arg;
    inet_aton(argv[1], &ip);
    ares_channel channel;
    ares_gethostbyaddr(channel, &ip, 4, AF_INET, dns_callback, arg);
    sleep(15);
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Why are you using 4 instead of `sizeof(in_addr)` for the address length in `ares_gethostbyaddr()`?

Comment: Oh. I checked a program that made use of this library and they used 4 so I assumed it was okay. I changed it to sizeof(ip) but it still segfaults.

Comment: Also, what is your sample input? And can you run it through gdb to see where exactly it crashes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You atleast have to [initialize](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ares_init) the ares_channel before you use it

```
 if(ares_init(&channel) != ARES_SUCCESS) {
   //handle error
  }
```

You also need an event loop to process events on the ares file descriptors and call [ares_process](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ares_process) to handle those events (more commonly, you'd integrate this in the event loop of your application)
There's nothing magic with ares, it doesn't use threads to do the async processing so simply calling sleep(15); doesn't let ares run in the "background"

Your callback should also inspect the `status` variable, you can't access `host->h_name` if the lookup failed.

A full example becomes:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <ares.h>

void dns_callback (void* arg, int status, int timeouts, struct hostent* host)
{
    if(status == ARES_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << host->h_name << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "lookup failed: " << status << '\n';
}
void main_loop(ares_channel &channel)
{
    int nfds, count;
    fd_set readers, writers;
    timeval tv, *tvp;
    while (1) {
        FD_ZERO(&readers);
        FD_ZERO(&writers);
        nfds = ares_fds(channel, &readers, &writers);
        if (nfds == 0)
          break;
        tvp = ares_timeout(channel, NULL, &tv);
        count = select(nfds, &readers, &writers, NULL, tvp);
        ares_process(channel, &readers, &writers);
     }

}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct in_addr ip;
    int res;
    if(argc < 2 ) {
        std::cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " ip.address\n";
        return 1;
    }
    inet_aton(argv[1], &ip);
    ares_channel channel;
    if((res = ares_init(&channel)) != ARES_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << "ares feiled: " << res << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    ares_gethostbyaddr(channel, &ip, sizeof ip, AF_INET, dns_callback, NULL);
    main_loop(channel);
    return 0;
  }
```

```
 $ g++ -Wall test_ares.cpp  -lcares
 $ ./a.out 8.8.8.8
google-public-dns-a.google.com
```

Comment: That was the mistake. I hadn't called ares_init. The program works now.

Comment: Too long time ago... but don't we first have to initialize library using `ares_library_init`?